# Ошибка "Found unknown categories in columns [2] during transform. These unknown categories will be encoded as all zeros"

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, optuna

Для подготовки признаков я использую следующий Pipeline:

```
num_features = ['registration_year', 'power', 'kilometer']
cat_features = ['vehicle_type', 'gearbox', 'model', 'fuel_type', 'brand', 'repaired']

num_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler())]
)

cat_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(drop='first', handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False))]
)

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', num_transformer, num_features),
        ('cat', cat_transformer, cat_features),
    ]
)
```

Затем я хочу найти лучшие гиперпараметры на кросс-валидации с помощью Optuna:

```
def objective_dtr(trial, X_train=features_train, y_train=target_train, random_state=RANDOM_STATE):     
    param = {    
        'max_depth': trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 1, 101, 1),
        'max_features': trial.suggest_categorical('max_features', ['sqrt', 'log2']),
        'min_samples_split': trial.suggest_int('min_samples_split', 2, 12, 1)
    }  
    model_DT = make_pipeline(preprocessor, 
                             DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=random_state, **param))
    mean_score = abs(cross_val_score(model_DT, X_train, y_train, cv=5, 
                                     scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error').mean())
    return mean_score

DT_study = optuna.create_study(sampler=SAMPLER, direction='minimize')
DT_study.optimize(objective_dtr, n_trials=75)
```

В процессе я постоянно получаю ошибку "Found unknown categories in columns [2] during transform. These unknown categories will be encoded as all zeros".

Как это исправить? Почему не срабатывает `handle_unknown='ignore'`?